# Tips needed for web application with mysql, google maps,

Tags: java, php, html, google-maps, web-applications

I want to make a web application that uses Google Maps API and stores some data in a MySQL Database.
I don't really know how to start and I would like some tips.

I'm not sure in what language I should write it.
I have quite some experience with Java and also made some small Java Web apps in the past.
But I also wouldn't mind learning about PHP, HTML/CSS, ...

What do you guys recommend to use?

I'm also wondering if I can run everything from my webspace, especially for data storage.
Should I write a Restful application for that?

Sorry if this is a little vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most google map applications are developed using javascript , php & mysql this is the route I would take.

There are numerous [demos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery) and [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/)
using these.

Answer (score 1):

Web development is a completely different beast from writing stand alone code. You **need** to learn about HTML and CSS no matter what framework you decide to go for. A basic knowledge of SQL will also help.

There are many PHP frameworks around, just do a google search. This will probably be the easiest route for a web app beginner.

If you already know some Java, AND you want to use Google's API, it might be worth checking out Google Web Tools (GWT). It compiles Java into JavaScript, so you can do the clever bits directly in Java.

I am personally in favour or Ruby on Rails currently, as it gives you quite a lot of flexibility, and it has a great support network. Plus you can deploy your app directly in Heroku.

Bear in mind that unless you are hosting the web server yourself, you are restricted to what the hosting service supports. Yahoo runs MySQL and PHP only as far as I know, for example.

Hope this helps. It's a whole universe so it pays to spend some time researching until you are confident of the route you are going to take.

Comment: okay, thanks for this answer. I have worked a bit with html/css before but it's quite some time ago. I have used a lot of sql as well. 
Thanks for the tip on using GWT. I will look into that. I will also have a look at Ruby on Rails. tnx